# How Enable MySQLi Extension on PHP7 (LAMP / CPANEL)?

Tags: php, apache, mysqli, cpanel, mariadb

My server upgraded to PHP7 and now I am getting an error which reads "Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress."

I have tried adding `extension=php_mysqli.so` to my PHP INI but that doesn't seem to help.  I am on a LAMP with CentOS and Apache 2.4 with MariaDB 10.0...  All was working before the update.  \

php -m shows:

```
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dba
dom
enchant
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
gmp
hash
iconv
imap
intl
ionCube Loader
json
ldap
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mhash
mysql
mysqli
mysqlnd
odbc
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
PDO_ODBC
pdo_pgsql
pdo_sqlite
pgsql
Phar
posix
pspell
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
snmp
soap
sockets
SourceGuardian
SPL
sqlite3
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tidy
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlrpc
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend Guard Loader
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend Guard Loader
Zend OPcache
the ionCube PHP Loader
```

Comment: did you restart the server after enabling the extension and checked in phpinfo?

Comment: If you're using CPanel, then use EasyApache to select the PHP modules, but this is not really programming related so off topic for stackoverflow.  PHP 7 no longer has the mysql extension, so make sure your version of Wordpress is compatible.

Comment: I did use EasyApache...

Comment: I can tell you that I don't think that `php -m` output that you edited the question with is from a php 7 install.

Comment: You did restart _Apache_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not solve your issue by adding MySQLi to php.ini, here you have install real mysqli extension on server that can be done Easyapache by enabling **MySQL Improved extension** , and it can be done by root user only. if you have than check below link.

Check full here: http://www.mochasupport.com/kayako/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=650